# Javascript error with JS API

Tags: javascript

Since a few days i have a JS error :

TypeError: this.player is undefined

This error is triggered when executing :

```
e.target.play();
```

Full code :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="player">
  <iframe src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x19u0oj?autoPlay=1&amp;volume=0&amp;logo=0&amp;highlight=ca0c1e" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="250" width="288">
  </iframe>
</div>
<script>
  // This code loads the Dailymotion Javascript SDK asynchronously.
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//api.dmcdn.net/all.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(e, s);
  }
   ());
  // This function init the player once the SDK is loaded
  window.dmAsyncInit = function()
  {
    var player = DM.player("player", {
      video: "x19u0oj", width: "288", height: "250", params: {
        api: true}
    }
                          );
    player.addEventListener("apiready", function(e)
                            {
                              e.target.play();
                            }
                           );
    player.addEventListener("playing", function(e)
                            {
                              e.target.setMuted();
                            }
                           );
  };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong ? 
I'm using this code to auto play the video in mute mode.

Comment: you are not using `this.player`, so the error must come from the plugin you are using. Did you init it correctly?

Comment: the this.player.playVideo() that is causing the problem is coming from the dailymotion SDK. It used to work a few days ago and suddenly no more ...